# Complex type hierarchy mapping leafs to `unknown` type

Tags: typescript, generics, types, interface

I'm trying to build a flexible generic base class for API facades. These facades would define a set of HTTP requests that return specific types. These definitions are used to build a registry of requests that is custom and tracked on a per-facade basis. I would like these requests to have all their type information available, however I think I'm having issues around mapped types because at its core I'm using a `FacadeResultTypes = Record<string, unknown>;

[Here is a TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-rFMIpxdFpjBB28Pjgvi4DIhJWqlSxMDU6g0mi1BSP0EbNauLSPrCxmyxW+3lJ6jpvMHaHfFMDf1x+1GDLQYD+AFlG3bE329b4IT-S1lGdORXSgjcfT9OE63pdomWXJM5XPOVO1nApcFQCF+EwZZUGkaRXEwf4Sn4GpMFROC7wfFsonbDlXBonEL1aYRlzaM1UGNTI2Lxd4TgPHAXxQj8bXtZgfxXGk1y9VDvn9GAg0TWUUzU0TbzxBDFQUFQFLQjQ00hctK3iPMZGkaNJNCe9H2fRBX3-NDLFrCgSDIYLiFgGAAFFbRiEjIXQfgTi4GBQpCkKKBqUpeBErhIuiwpPWQehsE3XSgOTKMsDk048zKgAmaNY1ZHZ-LSkodiyiKovyQo-00xSvxU391Ks74SrgO1crXS1oxyrqNIKugivEPNYFGbZ2QI0IYxiVBgAOebsExLhkCY3hMBOGhzgmA8u1kmsKAYzbxtm6TZPbVyhuHKTUBk4FvJmkievfNDgL0rsDPKzMK2ReIwSA5zo1BsbOpIkzDIDOAMdgZQshyABZfhkEwTsRI9T7QmUKEllWQCMYx0Nw35aMAAZYdp-SyujSGHIhJL62xvGCaJi65gWehVhmIDabFYROfs6HWYx2tadgeRLh2fjCJ9RsoZzRIamXf7uo+3qtfStr2i4ZYaBSRJ0HGFZ+y2HYxLgWtq3hWAfFeeQACEABlwtxyNKAAdXGFgMSelHvteyoEiUiaXt+-pnJgAlCE7NWWHZf4C1QZtpEqA4aGkJhEnuSUo7ymPk+c-oq8mkc08F9ILpJod4MpmENHj3V6PD6REn6PDNpkdALvToW7OhVZBlgKkrZtm6DAmGgDpFme1kOqf09b6Zs+1YQ9voOpQSM0mTe+Of6wAZTQdgWCRfVC4hBe3DSBuk7kxAU5o+vkerpaYe4M96707IbOahVUCbkGJ-Gu39f7SH-onMmOBgFlUsEAA) where I have recreated the type ecosystem. Upper portion is the setup of the hierarchy, and the lower portion is a limited example that reproduces my issue.

```
///////////////////
//  Types setup  //
///////////////////

// Convenience operator
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

// Describes an HTTP request's name and result type - implemented by an individual facade service.
// Note that the `unknown` type here is resulting in the issue.
type FacadeResultTypes = Record<string, unknown>;

// Defines a single type of request made by an API facade. Tracks number of inflight requests, errors, and latest value (value type is critical)
type FacadeRequest<T extends ValueOf<FacadeResultTypes>> = {
  inFlight: number;
  latest: T|undefined;
  error: string|undefined;
}

// A dictionary to look up FacadeRequests by name (name comes from the FacadeResultTypes keys, value is individual requests)
type FacadeRequestDictionary<ResultTypes extends FacadeResultTypes>
  = Record<keyof ResultTypes, FacadeRequest<ValueOf<ResultTypes>>>;

// Tracks the latest request to complete, as well as contains a FacadeRequestDictionary of all requests for the facade
type FacadeRequestRegistry<ResultTypes extends FacadeResultTypes> = {
  latest: FacadeRequest<ValueOf<ResultTypes>> | undefined;
  all: FacadeRequestDictionary<ResultTypes>;
}



/////////////////////
//  Example usage  //
/////////////////////

interface ExampleResponseType {
  test: string;
  test2: number;
}

interface ExampleFacadeResultTypes extends FacadeResultTypes {
  exampleRequest: ExampleResponseType;
  // other request name/response type pairs go in this list
}

const exampleRegistry: FacadeRequestRegistry<ExampleFacadeResultTypes> = {
  latest: undefined,
  all: {
    exampleRequest: {     // <-- Maps to facadeRequest<unknown>
      inFlight: 0,
      latest: undefined,  // <-- Maps to `unkonwn`
      error: undefined,
    }
    // Other request types defined in the ExampleFacadeResultTypes interface would show up here
  }
};

// PROBLEM:
// While exampleRegistry and exampleRegistry.all map to their correctly resolved types, exampleRegistry.all.exampleRequest maps to facadeRequest<unknown> and its child .latest also maps to unknown.
// I would like those `unknown` types to map to their corresponding FacadeResultTypes.

// Specifically, I want exampleRegistry.all.exampleRequest.latest to map to ExampleResponseType.
exampleRegistry.all.exampleRequest.latest;
```

As you can see, I would like to not have `unknown` (which then requires type casting by the implementer) to show up in the final references to the lowest-level elements in the hierarchy.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Convenience operator
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];
```

I'm not sure why you have this `ValueOf` type. That will just do:

```
Type A = { a: 1, b: 2 }
Type B = ValueOf<A> // 1 | 2
```

I don't see how this is helpful to your problem.

And if you remove that completely, I think everything works as you expect.

```
exampleRegistry.all.exampleRequest.latest; //  ExampleFacadeResultTypes | undefined
```

See [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQ19gUCAEMCoE8AOBTAzjdqAuBXZOEaCU8SEmAEQwGMAnASwCMMYBDAOxgAl54ACjHqoAjngw4A5Jk7sAtqg6cAJsIx4ANjhg4USgLQxG85JtSLOOVGuaJlx1YwBujFXnaaYAM3a12KkrY9K60qAB0lAByAPbWugAW7Do4CUoABnicANacMQDunOm6+jBpIsaYIuhaOIycAOaOiUqM6DURkHpoMABifgGoAEoa2khomAC8MCO0MfQqADzoOEyNADQwWbkFnAB8ANwUsDTe9WzsWPUN5iU9Md7q4pIw8oMwdg4AggIAkj4DQLhBD0PzZWR4eSsegwB6ObyaRgNBI6ETPFboTaoej0eaY5RqTTJF7OTwSGAAClJmnJ3VamAYjDq-k0AEouqV+v5AiN0ThFvAYKgAB7WVSYLmDEY1Mb6dB7GDTADekDg9V6iOROAAXDBOJDoUc4ETrCtdfAAD5ZQJnTg2I1CnHzXUrNYNK2qVC2+2QAC+x2AMC+MBUjFodRicno9hwMRgmhiMWyW0Ikp5YgkGI+9jkikpuaUc0UmG8uPkLT6gOGoxw4zY2VQiHx1PJbUcodc7k8T0zOHQ7Lple51b5VDDEajiEW0tqdcwIrFKglVZnsome1VipmqDmC0WDcQcNXtblmzTI9705rc72hwDILBmFSShNLzRvd0caLZlwqE27EwfJUE0LwAJgOYrHYepMEuc9eV7Mdw0YSN2GjWFHk8Lx30kEt5grXxhw5Ho4IzSQRgaNpVinY85yFUVUHFIcpWvOUFWVTdXzNJj0z5K8ZRPdcYAtLZPW9FQHUw3USNHcdkMnPjZ1Yo5-QoEgyHU4hYBgABRYUFB-LZ0HYBolBgTSNI0ih6msegCKUXT9PMaVkEjbA6xgFU4FNHUsFWa4HW8gAmXV9ShbFlKsqxsTsnS9NMcwSP42iFwYpduOrJK5Q8zcRUci9JF1Bz4oylzODc-QHVgOJyh7F4C2AapSuwO4lGQKD6EwBo43qRI20RFY-QoQdg2maTLyKn9EsU9cAG0pE46QAF0jkgCCVjovLyMo6MpJXUiVi210pwmhK9sywT2ONYkuOtL1zhUdZN0k7K4DgXLivggqPNeohA0WAwjAAWXYZAnzjAjmN47Y8kKDcfrVTgNSRFFdQABke+H42unzbrEzYzL+gGYGB0HPxgTIckjQp0k3H7sVxehdVx+6Mde-0ftgAB5Z8YWw9a6UwG17uaZ9Yryqa1zYazor8JR8hiLQ1HQBIChTMpsVQTd-V9FbYAEIZOYAIQAGW0wHtUoAB1BJGFud6f0OqiCQ2j7UAoo7wkw14QbJ59GBhXcRHDTR7GqGJNGcGwWvxe2nLd7bEE9kDwlj-L1reUnYwBYdPpWRZod2BUuDUJkGRtzQ1HCBaOE0dA4wzsGRJ2QpIlgf55cV+NGAbRIYmainm6KaOyYz320n98D5kayNQ0adKaLlSJU8d6Mk80FO4od-acCr7GjiAA)

Comment: This isn't quite right. I'm looking to make exampleRegistry.all.exampleRequest.latest to map to ExampleResponseType - which is the corresponding type in the ExampleFacadeResultTypes interface that is actually implemented. In your example it maps to `ExampleFacadeResultTypes | undefined`